# Not able to install mysqlclient

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am new to django but I know MySQL. However I wanted to connect django with mysql but is stuck at this point where I have to install mysqlclient but getting the error. I have already installed mysql server, created a virtualenv but still not able to install mysqlclient.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
```

Command "/home/devesh/django-apps/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-install-vaq3j43s/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-v5qqxse5/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/devesh/django-apps/myproject/myprojectenv/include/site/python3.5/mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-vaq3j43s/mysqlclient/

Comment: when you install mysqlclient, it contains some file that need to be compiled by gcc compiler, so you should have appropriate version of gcc installed on your machine with its path set to environment variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install packages

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev libffi-dev
```

Comment: On CentOS: `sudo yum install mysql-devel`